# How do you set a list with range of 5 using random numbers?

Tags: python

I am suppose to set up a list with a range of 5 plugging in your own numbers and then finding the sum of those numbers. I am stuck on how to do the range.

```
import math

list(range(1, 5))

n = input("Enter a number:  ")
range(1, 5)

#number.append(n) 

print(n)

#print(len(number))

while(True):
   n = (input("Enter a number: "))
   #number.append

   if(n == -1):
     break;

for i in range(1, 5):
    print(i)

#average = (len(number))
#average += (len(number))
print("Your average is: ")
```

Comment: I don't understand the requirement here. Are you trying to get five numbers from user input?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you just want to get a bunch of numbers from the user and then find their sum? What does it have to do with randomness or with a range of 5?

Comment: sorry to confuse you. I meant I am suppose to have a range of 5 from the users input and then getting the sum of those numbers.

Comment: When you say "have a range of 5 from the user's input," do you mean you're supposed to get 5 numbers from the user or that you're supposed to get several numbers *in* the range of 1 to 5? If the latter, you need to work through the requirements to figure out when to stop accepting numbers from the user.

Comment: I'd like to note that I'm the one who downvoted your question (and I've voted to close). I'm well aware that's unpleasant, but please don't get discouraged. The reason I did so is primarily because of the lack of clarity in the question about what exactly you're trying to do. Please work through the requirements and clarify what they are for us; if you're having trouble understanding them yourself, then start with getting that understanding. Understanding requirements and communicating them are fundamental skills in programming; you'll do yourself a favor if you start getting good at them now.

Answer (score 2):

Loop in `range(5)` appending each num the user enters then sum:

```
nums = []
for _ in range(5): # ask user to enter a num 5 times
    n = int(input("Enter a number")) # get and cast input to int
    nums.append(n) # append each num

print(sum(n)) # call sum on the list of 5 numbers
```

I presume by random you mean 5 numbers the user may enter.

Comment: @ytpillai,  apart from that being completely unpythonic by using a list comp for side effects, why would you do that instead of `nums = [ int(input("Enter a number")  for _ in range(5):]`?

Comment: Well, it's shorter for sure but I liked your second suggestion, which I should have realized. :P Thanks

Comment: @ytpillai, no worries, you should only use a list in python if you want to store data, using it for side effects is not really a good approach. I used a regular loop as the OP is struggling to understand something quite basic so better to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension:

```
randomNumbers = [int(input("enter a number")) for n in range(5)]
total = sum(randomNumbers)
average = sum(randomNumbers)/5
```

This will prompt the user to enter a number 5 times, each number will be added to the list

If you do just want to generate a list of random numbers as your title suggests:

```
>>>import random
>>>random.sample(range(1, 100), 5)

[96, 87, 3, 70, 46]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either let the computer generate random numbers like this:

```
import random #Put this at the top of the file for clarity
nums = []
[nums.append(random.randint(1, 5)) for x in range(0, 5)] #Replace list(range(0, 5)) with this.
```

One line for loops like this are basically a short hand way of writing something like `for x in range(0, 5): #Do stuff`.

Or, you could do this for user input.

```
#DO NOT IMPORT RANDOM HERE. THIS IS NOT A CODE I ACTUALLY MEAN IT DO NOT PUT IMPORT RANDOM FOR THIS CODE BECAUSE IT WILL BE POINTLESS
#Replace the list(0, 5) again
nums = []
[nums.append(int(input("Please enter a number")) for x in range(0, 5)]
```

Then, for the sum, add up every element

`total = sum(nums)`

Lastly, for the average.

```
print(total/len(nums)) #len(nums) is basically the length of the numbers array which is how many numbers you are adding
```

There is a three-line solution in case you want to surprise people.

```
def avg(arr):
    return sum(arr)/len(arr)

print(avg([int(input("Enter a number") for x in range(0, 5))]))
```